# Validation rule to throw an error "You cannot modify after business hours"

Tags: validation

I have a field and if the user tries to edit after 17:00 hours, error should be displayed that "You cannot modify after business hours"

Can any one help me how to write the validation rule for this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to validate based on Modified or Created Date.  Samples of formulas like that are here:

http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005091&language=en_US

However note that the time zone of that date might not be the same as your users.  This may or may not be a problem depending on how you are asserting the rule.

Answer (score 1):

Evaluate the if the field was changed using the ISCHANGED(field) operator, and compare the current time to your desired time using !Now().